# For a 2D Matrix, what is the faster way to apply a function to each cell of the matrix in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have the following function which I need to apply to each cell in a 2D matrix. My matrix can have upto 1 million cells. What is the faster way to calculate this? 
The function is as follows :

```
def walkRight(r,c,walls):
    global Pwalk
    global rows
    global columns
    sum = 0
    if c == (columns-1) or [r,c+1] in walls:
        sum = sum + Pwalk * U[r][c]
    else:
        sum = sum + Pwalk * U[r][c+1]
    if r == 0 or [r-1,c] in walls:
        sum = sum + 0.5*(1-Pwalk) * U[r][c]
    else:
        sum = sum + 0.5*(1-Pwalk) *  U[r-1][c]
    if r == rows-1 or [r+1,c] in walls:
        sum = sum + 0.5*(1-Pwalk) * U[r][c]
    else:
        sum = sum + 0.5*(1-Pwalk) * U[r+1][c]
    return sum
```

Comment: If you really need to apply this function to every cell then I believe there's really no choice other than iterating through everything which is O(n*n).

Comment: Or, how can I modify the function so that it can be applied to each cell ?

Comment: If you are applying your function to each and every cell you'd need to call it r * c times which would result in O(n*n) regardless of the way the function is defined. What you can do is think if there are cells that you don't need to apply this function to, and then think of some way of looking up only the cells you need. But to get help in that regard you'd need to show more of you code or explain what your program does so people can know what you're using `sum` for.

Comment: Try to come up with a calc that works with blocks of elements, for example `U[1:,:]`, or `U[:-1, 1:]`.

Comment: I think , that won't work. I am trying to solve a maze and so, for each cell I am trying to find the best move using value iteration. For value iteration , I need to find Utility for each cell. For each cell, I have 4 actions : Move Left, Move Right , Move Up and Move Down. The above code just shows one such function. But in actual problem, my utility will be max of values of each action. Hence for each cell I will have to apply 4 such functions as shown above  One such calculation for a matrix will be a single iteration. I need to iterate over new matrix again.This process is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you need to apply any function to every cell to solve a maze. If the maze is built based on a 2d matrix, that means that the object(person, rat, whatever) that is trying to find the exit can only move in four directions: up, down, left and right.

One of those directions is the one you came from so you can rule that one out, which leaves 3 possible moves. What you need to do then to solve the maze is check which of the 3 possible directions doesn't have a wall and follow that direction. Once you find a bifurcation, store this position and pick one of the 2 possible paths at random. If the path you choose leads to a dead end you go back to the bifurcation you came from and go the other way.

So a single recursive fucntion that when applied to one cell checks the 3 adjacent cells you did not come from should be enough to solve a 2d maze. I really don't see why you'd ever need to apply a function to every position of a maze.